# WordPress: Place smaller image with transparent background in front of image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, themes

I would like to place a smaller image with a transparent background in front of a header image in WordPress. The theme I am currently using allows me to set own css styles but I have no clue how to achieve my goal.

Has anybody already worked on this?

Thanks a ton,

Anton

Comment: Which theme you are using? Can you share your code?

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried. At least share some example code

Comment: we are not mind reader ... are you sure what you said is enough to give you an answer ? no code, no website, no screenshot, nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to place an image in front of another image. I placed a PNG of a bee inside a banner image.

[image]

#### HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <img id="banner" src="https://www.mortcap.com/images/sample_report_banner.png">
  <img id="bee" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/672c/f/2014/320/3/1/bee_png_stock_by_karahrobinson_art-d86m7bq.png">
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#banner {
  width: 600px;
}

#bee {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

When we set `position: absolute`, that element will always be position relative to the nearest parent with `position: relative` (or `absolute`). And then you can refine the position of the absolutely positioned element using `top, bottom, left, right` css properties.

Play arround with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nipunasudha/jtjgy9tm/1/)